# Android Studio under Network mound -

Tags: android, android-studio, network-programming, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following problem with Android Studio.

My files are located on a NAS server, which is connected to my local network. All devices communicate with more than 1000 MB on the LAN network.

When I move files, this also happens on average with 100 MiB, only in Android Studio when I build my project, it takes a long time and is very slow, below is an example.

```
11:58:03 External file changes sync may be slow: Project files cannot be watched (are they under network mount?)
12:07:10 Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 4m 48s 887ms
12:19:16 Gradle build finished in 11m 50s 45ms
12:25:50 Gradle build finished in 6m 0s 266ms
13:37:07 Gradle build finished in 7m 34s 183ms
13:57:52 Gradle build finished with 2 error(s) in 5m 3s 968ms
```

Can I set up a cache on my SSD for Android Studio or take other settings so that the bulding goes faster?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- SVN
- GitHub
- GitLab

and always have a local copy and work on it, when you feel you have done something worth making, push it to the remote server. This way you will never have problems like this.